# Structure - New Member Group to edit all pages

Tags: structure, entries

Is there any easy way to give a new member group permissions to edit all pages in my structure?
In the Member Group it has got Control Panel Access for all he Content Sections and The Add ons sectionand Modules Addon.
It has all Channel Posting Privelidges.
Channel Assignment as well it has got access to all the relevant ones as well.

But if a member in that group tries to access an entry in the structure they can't - it doesn't have the necessary permissions.
I need to go into the Entry Access Tab for the Entry and add the Group there.
There is a large no of pages in the structure so is there any easy way to add these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Structure is selected under "Module Access Privileges" (at the bottom of the form) along with "can access addons-section" and "can access addons-modules"

Comment: Yep those are both enabled but can't access pages already created - I think that is being overridden by the Entry Access Plugin possibly.

Comment: Under Channel Posting Privileges, is Can edit others entries checked Yes?

Comment: Yes that is ticked too

Comment: as a test, try removing that plugin and see what happens.

Comment: if that plugin is removed then added again will all the permissioned be set by it be retained? Can't lost them as large quantity of permissions set for large quantity of users.